# Error in using spark-cassandra-connector: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have a problem with running using `spark-cassandra-connector` with `spark-shell`.

In general, I follow [this tutorial](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/installing-the-cassandra-spark-oss-stack/) on 'Installing the Cassandra/Spark OSS Stack' by Amy Tobey for the "using spark-cassandra-connector" part. I see that:

- I manage to connect to Cassandra cluster

  ```
  INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
  ```
- but I am not able to run `count` method on the `table` object of `CassandraTableScanRDD` class

I have no idea how to interpret the console error output (googling it has not bring any effect) and I kindy ask for any hint of what am I doing wrong.

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

**1. running Spark with spark-cassandra-connector jar**

```
$ /usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.1.0/bin/spark-shell --jars /usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.1.0/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/03/30 01:17:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:40 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(martakarass, ); users with modify permissions: Set(martakarass, )
15/03/30 01:17:40 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/03/30 01:17:40 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP class server' on port 38860.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_31)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
15/03/30 01:17:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:42 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(martakarass, ); users with modify permissions: Set(martakarass, )
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@marta-komputer.home:48238]
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@marta-komputer.home:48238]
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 48238.
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20150330011743-7904
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port 55197.
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 55197 with id = ConnectionManagerId(marta-komputer.home,55197)
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager marta-komputer.home:55197 with 265.1 MB RAM
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-f69a93d0-da4f-4c85-9b46-8ad33169763a
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 38225.
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://marta-komputer.home:4040
15/03/30 01:17:43 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.1.0/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://192.168.1.10:38225/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1427671063959
15/03/30 01:17:44 INFO Executor: Using REPL class URI: http://192.168.1.10:38860
15/03/30 01:17:44 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@marta-komputer.home:48238/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/03/30 01:17:44 INFO SparkILoop: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
```

**2. Performing imports**

```
scala> 

scala> sc.stop
15/03/30 01:17:51 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://marta-komputer.home:4040
15/03/30 01:17:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterActor: MapOutputTrackerActor stopped!
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO ConnectionManager: Selector thread was interrupted!
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO ConnectionManager: ConnectionManager stopped
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext

scala> im15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
port com.15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
datastax.spark.connector._
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
15/03/30 01:17:52 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

**3. Defining `spark.cassandra.connection.host`, defining `SparkContext`**

```
scala> val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@e6e5da4

scala> val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "test", conf)
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: martakarass,
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(martakarass, ); users with modify permissions: Set(martakarass, )
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:35080]
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:35080]
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35080.
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20150330011754-63ea
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port 32973.
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 32973 with id = ConnectionManagerId(localhost,32973)
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:32973 with 265.1 MB RAM
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-630cc34e-cc29-4815-b51f-8345250cb030
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 43669.
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://localhost:4040
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.1.0/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://192.168.1.10:43669/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1427671074181
15/03/30 01:17:54 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@localhost:35080/user/HeartbeatReceiver
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@118a4d5
```

**4. Using `cassandraTable` function to build object of `CassandraTableScanRDD` class**

```
scala> val table = sc.cassandraTable("twissandra", "invoices")
table: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15
```

**5. Calling `count` function on the object of `CassandraTableScanRDD` class**

```
scala> table.count
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:243
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:243) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(reduce at CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:243)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (CassandraTableScanRDD[1] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15), which has no missing parents
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5320) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278019440
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.2 KB, free 265.1 MB)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 0 (CassandraTableScanRDD[1] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 26342 bytes)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO Executor: Fetching http://192.168.1.10:41700/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1427672382104
15/03/30 01:39:43 INFO Utils: Fetching http://192.168.1.10:41700/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /tmp/fetchFileTemp97270090697167118.tmp
15/03/30 01:39:44 INFO Executor: Adding file:/tmp/spark-0a658f91-717f-4c30-8fe2-979c8c1399a7/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to class loader
15/03/30 01:39:44 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
15/03/30 01:39:44 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
15/03/30 01:39:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.isStopped()Z
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource$.instance(CassandraConnectorSource.scala:53)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.metrics.InputMetricsUpdater$.apply(InputMetricsUpdater.scala:53)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 01:39:44 ERROR ExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.isStopped()Z
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource$.instance(CassandraConnectorSource.scala:53)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.metrics.InputMetricsUpdater$.apply(InputMetricsUpdater.scala:53)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 01:39:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.isStopped()Z
        org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource$.instance(CassandraConnectorSource.scala:53)
        com.datastax.spark.connector.metrics.InputMetricsUpdater$.apply(InputMetricsUpdater.scala:53)
        com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.compute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:194)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
        org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
        org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 01:39:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/03/30 01:39:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/03/30 01:39:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is a common indication of a version mismatch: One of your dependencies was compiled against a more recent version of another dependency and at runtime is provided with an earlier version that does not have that new method.

In this case, you are trying to run `Spark-Cassandra Connector 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` against `Spark 1.1.0`.  Try to align those versions. Either use a 1.3.0 release of Spark of a 1.1.0-compatible version of the spark-cassandra connector.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took me so long to validate your answer. I finally upgraded to Spark 1.2.0 and followed version compatibility table from [the documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). Today there is no release of the Connector of 1.2 version, but I used [Release 1.2.0 RC 3](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/releases/tag/v1.2.0-rc3) and so far (simple examples) it does work!

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time in a similar Error. It is a version mismatch indeed.
I found a version compatibility table that could help others as well [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) .

[Version Compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNVfN.png)